# Long-term travel with a 3-month-old baby through a country?

Tags: air-travel, health, children, long-term

My girlfriend and I are wondering if it is possible/recommended/safe to travel with a 3-month-old baby through a country (New Zealand) for about 3 to 4 months. We are just thinking about it. We haven't planned anything. So this is the first attempt to get some information about the feasibility.

The only thing we are sure about yet is travelling through the country by car. Probably even a car in which we can sleep. So another thing would be that we only make day trips and always have the car as savepoint where we come back to.

Do you have any experience travelling with babys about the age of 3 months?

Comment: How do you plan to travel?  Babies require a lot of stuff, formulas, bottles, diapers, cremes, soaps, strollers, car seat.  Not the easiest to deal with hopping on and off buses, trains or planes.  Would likely be best in a rented camper van.  Plus you have to consider inoculations as there are a bunch at 4 and 6 months.

Comment: By car. (added some information, about how we think to travel)

Comment: it's not really about opions (we know most people would say: Don't do it!) we are looking for some initial information. Maybe if some people have already made some experience. It's really hard to find some good informations about long-term traveling with young babys.

Comment: @obrob, there's probably a reason for that (hint, hint). A toddler is already a difficult enough proposition when in the safety and confort of your own home, so on the road... Also don't forget that some parts of NZ are pretty isolated. When your kid will catch a fever and you won't have easy access to a doctor or medication, you might be in quite a predicament.

Comment: I would talk with your pediatrician, as I mentioned earlier there are a number of recommended inoculations and for my daughter I would not be too keen on simply showing up at some random doctor's office to get her next round of shots, I'd want the doctor that cared for her and my wife's pregnancy keeping an eye on things.  We didn't do any long haul traveling until my daughter was 2.

Comment: I've lived in NZ for life except when travelling overseas occasionally. If there are ANY countries in the world where this is a good idea then NZ will be about top of the list. As a local, I'd happily do it - or, would have done so about 38 years ago when my daughter was 3 months old. Even then, the answer would have been "as safe and as suitable as anywhere on earth". Hopefully you plan to do this outside Winter (unless skiing and snow or rain are of particular interest :-). NZ is mild compared to eg Germany BUT summer is nicer. | If you do day trips you will be in easy reach of good ...

Comment: ... enough facilities essentially anywhere sensible in NZ. Even touring aand camping the most inaccessible possible place in NZ is under a day to drive to a major city, much less to a minor town. Essentially everywhere is in cellphone coverage (choose a sensible network). If you are snowed in or the bridges are washed out (very occasionally happens) or the car broken and your baby is sick they **WILL** send a helicopter and almost certainly not charge you if life is or may have been at risk. (They are nice people here :-).) |...

Comment: DO come to NZ. You'll love it. Spring is showing signs of Sprunging about now so any time from now on for 8 or so months is OK BUT I'd avoid the next month or two if you have a choice as eg late October on is nicer. Our hottest period if you like sun is late Jan early Feb but the summer can often last a long long time after that. You are welcome to contact me for other information - see my profile for email.

Comment: @jcaron there's very few places in NZ that tourists go to that are more than a couple of hours from a GP.